# How to separate MassTransit demo into producer and consumer applications

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit

I am trying to separate the MassTransit demo (https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/quickstart.html) into two separate applications, but my consumer application is not receiving any messages.

I have created 3 projects: Send, Receive, and Messages. Send contains a `Send` class which is my producer code, Receive contains a `Receive` class which is my consumer code, and Messages contains classes for my messages.

Here is my `Send` class:

```
using MassTransit;
using Messages;
using System;

namespace MassTransitTest
{
    class Send
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                var host = config.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), c =>
                {
                    c.Username("guest");
                    c.Password("guest");
                });
            });

            bus.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Publishing message");

            bus.Publish(new TextMessage() { Text = "Testing 12345" });

            bus.Stop();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my `Receive` class:

```
using MassTransit;
using Messages;
using System;

namespace Receive
{
    class Receive
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(config =>
            {
                var host = config.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), c =>
                {
                    c.Username("guest");
                    c.Password("guest");
                });

                config.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "queue", endpoint =>
                {
                    endpoint.Handler<TextMessage>(context =>
                    {
                        return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"{context.Message.Text}");
                    });
                });
            });

            bus.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Receive listening for messages");

            Console.ReadLine();

            bus.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is my `TextMessage` class:

```
using System;

namespace Messages
{
    public class TextMessage
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I send the message from my `Send` class I would like to receive it and output it to the console from my `Receive` class.

Comment: If you look at the broker management console, do you see the queues and exchanges creating and the appropriate bindings for the message type?

Comment: Yes, @ChrisPatterson. But I don't see any messages reaching those exchanges/queues once I call `bus.Publish()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! `Publish` is an asynchronous message that returns a `Task`, so I needed to `await` and then everything worked. My `Send` program was exiting before the message was fired off.